# Почему-бы не оформлять комментарии сразу как чат?

Tags: предложение, комментарии, чат

Почему-бы на этом сайте не оформлять комментарии сразу как чат? Хотя бы для того, чтобы не напрягать админов лишней работой по перемещению комментариев в чат? А всех остальных не заставлять нажимать 100500 ссылок, чтобы поглядеть обсуждение. :-(

Comment: Не все пользователи могут заходить и отправлять сообщения в чате. При определенных условиях система сама предлагает перенести дискуссию в чат и автоматически создает комнату.

Comment: [Не все пользователи могут заходить и отправлять сообщения в чате] Святые трансляторы и пророки их Ахо, Сети и Ульман, кто же в 21 веке не может заходить и отправлять сообщения в чате?

Comment: Например те, у которых не хватает репутации, либо заблокирован домен чатов.

Comment: [Например те, у которых не хватает репутации, либо заблокирован домен чатов] Если репы нехватает чтобы чатиться, то ее нехватает и чтобы комментить. Или у вас и по чтению все блокируется? А если коменты принудительно перенесены в чат, то как быть лишенцам? Вобщем загадка загадочной стаковерфловской души. В любом случае, если сразу иметь коменты в виде чата, то ничто не изменится. Все любимые сердцу админа запреты и баны останутся такими же. Просто форма коментов станет сразу чатом и не надо будет бегать по ссылкам чтобы поглядеть обсуждение.

Comment: Ваше предложение очень хорошее, но даже если он здесь получит огромную поддержку, то оно не будет не реализовано, так как изменение функциональности работы не будет разрабатываться лишь для этого сайта сети StackExchange. Чтобы это реализовать есть смысл перевести предложение на английский и спросить на [главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Предложение очень хорошее, но с текущей реализацией чатов есть проблемы: они через 14 дней неактивности "замораживаются", если было хотя бы 15 сообщений от минимум двух человек, в противном случае, они удаляются через 7 дней.

Comment: Вы правда нажимаете 100500 ссылок для перехода в чат? Приведите первые 10 хотя бы плиз, для пождкрепления аргумента )

Comment: [Приведите первые 10 хотя бы плиз] Если просматривать 10 вопросов в которых обсуждение вынесено в чат вот вам и будет 10 ссылок, по которым надо пойти, а потом вернуться. Кроме того, в вопросе может быть несколько ответов, в каждом из которых обсуждение вынесено в чат. Вот вам и 100500 ссылок по которым надо пойти а потом вернуться, чтобы понять о чем идет речь в обсуждении. Все это очень неудобно.

Comment: То есть вы просто хотите почитать все подряд? Тогда, наверно, открывайте Чат и там все комнаты подряд читайте ... Лично я перехожу в чат от вопроса не более пары раз в месяц .. Тащить для этого чаты в комментарии и провоцировать простынки обсуждений - не вижу смысла.

Answer (score 5):

Комментарии не предназначены для обсуждений, их предназначение - конкретизировать пост или же внести дополнительные детали, недостаточные для создания самостоятельного поста при условии, если вносящий детали не хочет корректировать сам пост.

Чаты, в свою очередь, как раз таки предназначены для обсуждений.

Предложение системы перенести комментарии в чат - не более чем предположение о том, что комментарии используются не по назначению, основанное на их большом количестве. Если под постом большое количество важных комментариев - им и место под постом, а не в чате.

Хотите прочитать обсуждение - переходите по ссылке в чат, большинству же, ищущих ответ на свой вопрос, важны только комментарии, дополняющие ответ. Мало кто захочет искать важные для себя моменты в длинной ленте обсуждения, это не практично и идет вразрез с идеологией ресурса (построением удобной базы знаний).

Comment: Выглядит логично, но когда приходит модератор, он переносит ***все*** комментарии в чат, независимо от их функций. Надо ли модераторам изменить этот шаблон поведения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP а вот про этот аспект я не знал. В моем понимании - надо менять. Важным дополнениям - место под постом, их перенесение мне кажется нелогичным и деструктивным. В идеале нужно все комментарии копировать в чат, а из под поста удалять все кроме значимых.

Answer (score 3):

Затем, что это не форум. Вопросы здесь не предназначены для обсуждений. Сила SO/SE в формате "четкий вопрос" - "четкий ответ". Комментарии - лишь необходимое зло для уточнения деталей.

Задавайте вопросы и давайте более четкие ответы, и надобности в комментариях не будет.

---

ruSO входит в большую семью сайтов STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK (посмотрите ссылки в подвале страницы) использующих единый движок. Для внесения изменений в движок - предложение должно быть сделано на [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) и в случае принятия, оно распространится на все сайты группы. Спойлер - маловероятно что это случится.

Comment: Ну так оформите это необходимое зло сразу в форму чата. Все равно у вас получается чат на месте комментариев. Так сделайте сразу чат, зачем еще какая-то промежуточная форма, после которой надо еще куда-то идти по ссылке? Сделайте сразу чат под вопросом. Кто хочет, будет читать обсуждение в чате. Кто не хочет, не будет разворачивать чат, а будет читать только вопросы-ответы и наливаться неимоверной силой SO/SE.

Comment: **`Сделайте сразу чат под вопросом`** -- мне нравится такая идея

Comment: Мне тоже нравится. Но админам эта идея почему-то не нравится.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а с чего вы взяли, что админам она не нравится, вы уже спрашивали на Мете SE?

Comment: [вы уже спрашивали на Мете SE] Чтоза мета SE? Я знаю этот сайт и не знаю никакой меты SE. И я спрашиваю на том сайте, который посещаю. Какая там еще мета SE? Может Вы мне еще в администрацию Трампа писать прикажете?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 изучите вопрос. ruSO входит в большую семью сайтов STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK (посмотрите ссылки в подвале страницы) использующих единый движок. Для внесения изменений в движок - предложение должно быть сделано на https://meta.stackexchange.com/ и в случае принятия, оно распространится на все сайты группы. Спойлер - маловероятно что это случится.

Comment: Зачем тогда русская мета, если здесь ничего не решают, а все решают на английской мете?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 пожалуйста перестаньте использовать манипулятивные приемы в своей речи - это неконструктивно.

Comment: Нет, серьезно. Есть русская мета. Я пишу на нее предложение. А мне говорят - пиши предложение на английскую мету. Тогда вопрос - а зачем существует русская мета? Для красоты что-ли?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вот вы любите много читать, прочитайте последние 50 вопросов на русской Мете и увидите, какие вопросы тут решаются.

Comment: Читать я не люблю, но для такого случая я поглядел, какие вопросы тут решаются/обсуждаются. Не 50 конечно но десяток сообщений просмотрел. Вобщем никакие вопросы тут не решаются, одна болтовня. И болтают ее три с половиной персоны, как раз те самые, которые постоянно у меня вычеркивают "добрый день" в вопросах. В свое время все пытался у них узнать, почему им кажется что "добрый день" это неприлично и его надо вычеркивать, но так и не получил внятного ответа. То есть бота вычеркивающего приветствия тут посадить могут, а решить что-то по делу не могут. Тогда все ясно. Удачи вам, админы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 50 вопросов именно потому, что решение принимается не моментально, а занимает некоторое время. Логично что свежие вопросы (те 10 что вы пролистали) будут скорее всего нерешенными ;-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1, те, кого вы называете админами, являются таковыми с вероятностью 0.00%. Более того, это обычные участники, такие же, как Вы.